# Does keycloak support mongodb as a database?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2, keycloak-services

We can use PostgreSQL or MySQL as DB for keycloak but I want to use mongo DB as database for keycloak.
is there any way to implement this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although MongoDB was once supported in Keycloak, it has since been removed. Per the offical Keycloak documentation, a relational database is required for the persistent datastore:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_database

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB support was removed, more info here:

https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-February/009417.html